# Automatically Add Alt Tag to Product Images - OSCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo, oscommerce

I want to automatically add Alt Tags for all my product images.

I am using OSCommerce. - I would like to preferably add all product images alt tags to be the same as the product names, or similar - can this be done with a script of some sort?

I would be very grateful for the help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its absolutely possible to add `Alt` tag dynamically via JQuery to all of your `<img>` tag present on page.

Assuming that you have `<img>` tags as follows:

```
<img class="productimage" title="Some Product Name" 
     src="http://someserver/somepath/images/product_1983212.jpg">
```

To Add `Alt` tag dynamically you can try following approach.

1) Load [JQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) into HTML page's `<head>` tag if its not there.

2) Add jQuery document ready event handler which will add `alt` tags dynamically as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".productimage").each(function(){
        var currentTitle = $(this).attr("title");
        $(this).attr("alt",currentTitle);
    });

});
```

Above code will iterate over all `<img>` tag having `class="productimage"` and will read its `title` and add `alt` equal to `title`.

Hope this will help you a bit.

**Edit:**

By looking at your Product detail page, I came up with following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#product-info-wrapper").each(function(){
        var currentProdTitle = $(this).find("#product-header").find("span[itemprop=name]").text();
        $(this).find("#product_image_holder > img").each(function(){ 
            $(this).attr("alt",currentProdTitle); 
        });
    });
});
```

Modified the code to consider situation where you have multiple `#product-info-wrapper` into single page.

Comment: Hi

Wow! Great advice Vijay! - However I am unsure how exactly to implement this.

 I can see in my site I have <img source> tags, so I assume this is enough to make the "get name" type function work.

however they do not all use class=productImage - so this is an issue isnt it ? Here is an example of one of my products:

https://www.pmctelecom.co.uk/plantronics-hw261-supraplus-wideband-binaural

also which file should I be putting this script in, the header file?

Thanks Vijay

Comment: Okay so this is my code so far:

$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".productimage").each(function(){
        var currentTitle = $(this).attr("title");
        $("img:not([alt])").attr("alt",currentTitle);
    });

});

Comment: wow you are the man

- I have read a fair amount about Jquery today and I feel I have learned a lot - where do I put this code? 

- Will it run everytime a product page is loaded? if so can i delete it after its run and keep the code for another time?

Thanks so much

Comment: Hello Steve. I just checked PDP and found that we don't have jQuery loaded onto that page. Can its possible to modify that page to add it by following step 1 mentioned above.

Comment: Yes I can do that - but to which page do I add it?

I have .TPL files for index etc, i dont really want to add the script manually to 1000+ pages?

Also - after they are named can i delete the code and save it elsewhere for future use?
Many Thanks

Comment: It should be added to Master Page or something like that so that you don't need to modify all other pages. Just search through your code base and see how `<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js">` is getting added to `<head>` tag. Regarding deletion of code - you really don't need to delete that code as above `$(document).ready()` code will just add the `alt` tag dynamically while rendering that page inside browser. This will not modify your actual view files.

Comment: hey, I think I found it. I have 2 files. One called index.tpl and one called product_info.tpl - which seems the right one.

Here is an example of the code from the top:

{include 'catalogue/breadcrumb.tpl'}
<div id="product-info-wrapper" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

 <div id="product-header">
  <div style="float: left;">

Is this the right place to put it, where abouts specifically? I'm nearly there now Vijay!

Comment: I found master.tpl - this the one ?